# How to use select tag in html to choose specific sqlite3 queries with php?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

What I have tried is to use an if statement and the switch statement  but it still does not work as it goes to the default: "something went wrong" which I have coded in, but I'm not sure what went wrong

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formSelect">
        
            <div id="chosen">
            
            <label for="pkCountry" class="blue">Choose a country:</label>
            
            <select name="chooseCountry" id="choose">
                
                <option value="start">select...</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                 <option value="India">India</option>
                 <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                 <option value="England">England</option>
                 <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                 <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                 <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                 <option value="West Indies">West Indies</option>
            
            </select>
                
                <?php
                 $db = new SQLite3('cricket.db');

                        if (!$db) {
                             echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
                           } 
                       else {
                            switch (isset($_POST['formCountry'])){
                              case 'India':
                              $command = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'India';");
                              
                              $db->exec($command);
                                  
                            break;
                              case 'Australia':
                               $command1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'Australia';");
                              
                              $db->exec($command1);
                                  
                            break;
                                  
                              case 'England':
                                  $command2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'England';");
                              
                              $db->exec($command2);
                                  
                            break;
                                  
                              case 'Pakistan':
                                  $command3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'Pakistan';");
                              
                                  $db->exec($command3);
                                  
                            break;
                                  
                              case 'Bangladesh':
                                  $command4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'Bangladesh';");
                              
                                 $db->exec($command4);
                            break;
                                  
                             case 'Sri Lanka' :
                                  $command5 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'Sri Lanka';");
                              
                                  $db->exec($command5);
                                  
                           break;
                                  
                              case 'South Africa':
                                 $command6 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'South Africa';");
                              
                                 $db->exec($command6);
                                  
                                break;
                                  
                              case 'West Indies':
                                  $command7 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country = 'West Indies';");
                              
                                  $db->exec($command7);
                                break;
                              default:
                                  echo "<br>something went wrong</br>";                                 
                                  $db->close();
                                 
                                  
                          }  
                             
                
                        
                        
                        }
                        
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select name is `chooseCountry` while you're looking for `$_POST['formCountry']`

You should update your switch to

```
switch ($_POST['chooseCountry']){
```

Furthermore the `isset` function only returns booleans, `true` or `false`. You can not use it in the switch. If you want to avoid warnings, you need to add an if before the switch

```
if(isset($_POST['chooseCountry'])) {
    switch ($_POST['chooseCountry']){
        // CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think the fetchArray() function have to be used to get the records from sqlite.

Comment: Well for sure if you need to return the values from the SELECt you need the SQLite3. I thought that part was later in your code. But before that have you fixed the issued above?

Comment: yep, thanks for the corrections but it's still not working, I think there has to be an error with the SQLite3 part of the code as the query is not working. BTW i do have the fetchArray function later on in my code, just wanted to know if it had to be implanted again.